# How to add bitmaps to array in Android Development

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a game and I wanted to ask how can I store all my bitmaps into an Array map.
This is the method I'm now using:

```
Bitmap MyBitmap;
```

And is there a faster way to draw bitmaps:

```
GameView.drawBitmap(MyBitmap, 0, (i-30)*cellHeight+bac, null);
```

Comment: if you store Multiple Bitamp in array then may be chance to happen out of memory so instead store Bitamp just store respective path and try  load from path when needed.

Comment: Did you know about LruCache, LruCache is designed to handle multiple bitmaps in the application as well as handling memory utilization of thr application.

Comment: store path..and use caching..to avoid out of memory exception..